# Changing the order of a double integral, polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

Change the order of the following double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\sin\theta}r\theta drd\theta$$

**My attempt:**

I got

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\arcsin r}r\theta drd\theta$$

as $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and therefore $\sin\frac{\pi}{2} = 1$

and if $\sin \theta = r,$ then $\arcsin r = \theta$

Would this be correct?

Comment: I do not agree with the bounds in your attempt. Have you drawn a figure and marked the actual domain? It might help...

Comment: I have, I get a quarter circle with radius $ \sin \theta$

Answer (score 1):

The current integral says that $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $0<r<\sin (\theta)$. You can plot a graph to help yourself. In $0<\theta<\pi/2$ the function $r=r(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ is injective so there is no need to split the integral.

Now, when $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $0<r<\sin (\theta)$, this means that $r$ is at minimum 0 and at most it can be $1$ when $\theta=\pi /2$, so $0<r<1$. Whenever $0<r<1$ then $\theta$ runs between $\arcsin (r)$ and $\pi/2$ (just apply the inverse of $\sin$ at both sides).

In a summary we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sin (\theta)} r \theta dr d\theta=\int_0^{1} \int_{\arcsin(r)}^{\pi/2} r \theta d\theta dr.$$

I hope it helped. Good luck!